# Sobrepor gráfico no R

Tags: r

como posso sobrepor dois ou mais gráficos sem que os limites dos eixos também apareçam sobrepostos na figura?

```
a = rnorm(1000)
b = runif(1000)
plot(a, type = "l")
par(new = T)
plot(b, type = "l", col = "blue", xlab = "", ylab = "")
#os eixos de y ficam sobrepostos
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o teu objetivo for o mesmo do exemplo, uma solução é usar o `matplot()`

```
a = rnorm(1000)
b = runif(1000)
matplot(cbind(a, b), type = 'l')
```

Também é possível fazer com o `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(a = a, b = b, x = 1:1000)) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = a, colour = 'a')) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = b, colour = 'b'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de desenhar os dois gráficos, você pode desenhar o primeiro gráfico, e depois adicionar somente as linhas da segunda série. Com isso você terá os dois gráficos "sobrepostos"

```
a = rnorm(1000)
b = runif(1000)
plot(a, type = "l")
lines(b, col = "blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desabilitar os eixos de um dos gráficos para não ficarem sobrepostos, utilizando `axes=FALSE`. Para não ter subtítulos sobrepostos, pode usar `ann=FALSE`.

Segue, abaixo, seu código com as dicas já adicionadas:

```
a = rnorm(1000) 
b = runif(1000)
plot(a, type = "l")
par(new = T)
plot(b, type = "l", col = "blue", axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
#os eixos de y não estão mais sobrepostos
```