# Sobrepor gráficos no R com o ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Olá, considere dois data frames:

df = a quantidade de alunos que responderam os itens A,B,C,D e E de uma prova de 6 questões

```
 ITENS <-c("A","B","C","D","E")
 Q.1 <-c(10,20,10,40,10)
 Q.2 <-c(5,25,0,50,10)
 Q.3 <-c(15,20,5,40,10)
 Q.4 <-c(15,30,5,30,5)
 Q.5 <-c(20,25,5,20,15)
 Q.6 <-c(10,20,10,40,10)
 df <- data.frame(ITENS,Q.1,Q.2,Q.3,Q.4,Q.5,Q.6)
```

df2 = é o gabarito das questões

```
 Q.01 <-c(0,20,0,0,0)
 Q.02 <-c(5,0,0,0,0)
 Q.03 <-c(0,0,5,0,0)
 Q.04 <-c(0,0,0,30,0)
 Q.05 <-c(20,0,0,0,0)
 Q.06 <-c(0,0,10,0,0)
 df2 <- data.frame(ITENS,Q.01,Q.02,Q.03,Q.04,Q.05,Q.06)
```

Assim crio dois dataframes: long e long2

```
 library(tidyr)
 long <- df %>% gather(turma, quantidade, Q.1:Q.6)
 long2 <- df2 %>% gather(turma, quantidade, Q.01:Q.06)
```

e ploto os gráficos de cada data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long)+geom_bar(aes(x = ITENS, y = quantidade, fill ="red"),stat = 
"identity")+facet_wrap(~turma)+guides(fill=FALSE)

ggplot(long2)+geom_bar(aes(x = ITENS, y = quantidade),stat = "identity")+          
facet_wrap(~turma) +guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Os gráficos ficam em páginas separadas,a **ideia era sobrepor esses dois gráficos**. De tal forma que no gráfico da quantidade de alunos que reponderam os itens aparecesse o gabarito da questão em vermelho.

Já tentei de várias formas as soluções apresentadas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123012/sobrepor-gr%C3%A1ficos-com-ggplot2) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85844/sobrepor-gr%C3%A1fico-no-r), mas sem sucesso.

Até consigo sobrepor, mas aí eu teria que fazer um gráfico de cada vez:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(a = Q.1, b = Q.01, x = df$ITENS)) + geom_bar(aes(x = 
x, y = Q.1 , fill = "red"),stat = "identity") + geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = Q.01, 
fill= "blue"),stat = "identity")
```

Att.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu fiz algumas alterações no seu código.

Eu alterei o nome das variáveis do `df2` para `Q.1`, `Q.2`, `Q.3`, `Q.4` e `Q.5`.

Em `long2` eu chamei a variável de `gabarito` porque representa a quantidade de alunos que acertaram as respectivas questões, certo?

Depois eu uni `long` e `long2` pelos `ITENS` e o que você chamou de `turma` (por isso que modifiquei os nomes das variáveis em `df2`).

Segue código e resultado:

```
ITENS <-c("A","B","C","D","E")
Q.1 <-c(10,20,10,40,10); Q.2 <-c(5,25,0,50,10); Q.3 <-c(15,20,5,40,10)
Q.4 <-c(15,30,5,30,5); Q.5 <-c(20,25,5,20,15); Q.6 <-c(10,20,10,40,10)
df <- data.frame(ITENS,Q.1,Q.2,Q.3,Q.4,Q.5,Q.6)

Q.1 <-c(0,20,0,0,0); Q.2 <-c(5,0,0,0,0); Q.3 <-c(0,0,5,0,0)
Q.4 <-c(0,0,0,30,0); Q.5 <-c(20,0,0,0,0); Q.6 <-c(0,0,10,0,0)
df2 <- data.frame(ITENS,Q.1,Q.2,Q.3,Q.4,Q.5,Q.6)

library(tidyr)
long <- df %>% gather(turma, quantidade, Q.1:Q.6)
long2 <- df2 %>% gather(turma, gabarito, Q.1:Q.6)

library(dplyr)
l <- left_join(long, long2, by = c("ITENS", "turma"))
ggplot(l, aes(x = ITENS)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = quantidade, fill = "red"), stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  guides(fill = F) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = gabarito, fill = "blue"), stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~turma)
```

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3):

Acho que entendi o que você quer fazer.

```
# Vou mudar o seu df2.
df2 <- data.frame(turma = c("Q.1", "Q.2", "Q.3", "Q.4", "Q.5", "Q.6"), 
                             gabarito = factor(c("B", "A", "C", "D", "A", "C"), 
                             levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

# unir long e df2
library(dplyr)
long <- left_join(long, df2)

# construir o gabarito 
long <- long %>% transform(gabarito = (gabarito == ITENS))

# o grafico
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long) + geom_bar(aes(x = ITENS, y = quantidade, fill = gabarito), stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~turma)
```

Acho que te induzi a um nome inadequado. No lugar de 'turma' é mais adequado 'questão'.

Nossa. É praticamente cópia do que o Rafael fez. Mas quando eu comecei a fazer, ele não tinha publicado a sua resposta.